# User is Null when using a Service over UserManager

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, single-page-application

Using Angular 7 and [OIDC-Client](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js) I created an AuthService that exposes a few UserManager methods.

When I call `signInRedirectCallback` from the AuthService the user is `null`.

If I call it using UserManager directly the user is not `null`.

More details below:

```
const settings : UserManagerSettings = {
  authority: 'https://localhost:5005',
  client_id: 'spa',
  redirect_uri: 'https://localhost:5001/signin',
  post_logout_redirect_uri: 'https://localhost:5001/signout',
  response_mode: 'query',
  response_type: 'code',
  scope: 'openid profile email offline_access api',
  filterProtocolClaims: true,
  loadUserInfo: true
};

@Injectable({ 
  providedIn: 'root' 
})

export class AuthService {

  private manager = new UserManager(settings);
  private user: User = null;

  constructor() {

    this.manager.getUser().then(user => {
      this.user = user;
    });

  }

  isSignedIn(): boolean {
    return this.user != null && !this.user.expired;
  }

  getClaims(): any {
    return this.user.profile;
  }

  signInRedirect(args?: any): Promise<void> {
    return this.manager.signinRedirect(args);
  }

  signInRedirectCallback(url?: string): Promise<void> {
    return this.manager.signinRedirectCallback(url).then(user => {
      this.user = user;
    });
  }

 // Other methods

}
```

I have an AuthenticateGuard as follows:

```
export class AuthenticatedGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) : boolean {

    if (this.authService.isSignedIn())
      return true;

    this.authService.signInRedirect({ state: { url: state.url }});
    return false;

  }

}
```

Then my callback component is the following:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { AuthService } from '../shared/services/auth.service'
import { UserManagerSettings, UserManager } from 'oidc-client';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'signin',
  templateUrl: './signin.component.html'
})

export class SignInComponent implements OnInit {
  private manager = new UserManager(settings);
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.manager.signinRedirectCallback().then(function (user) {
       console.log(user);
    });
  }
}
```

On the callback component `user` is undefined when I use `console.log(user)`.

To make this work I needed to create a new UserManager on the SignInComponent (Callback Component) instead of using the AuthService, e.g.:

```
const settings : UserManagerSettings = {
  authority: 'https://localhost:5005',
  client_id: 'spa',
  redirect_uri: 'https://localhost:5001/signin',
  post_logout_redirect_uri: 'https://localhost:5001/signout',
  response_mode: 'query',
  response_type: 'code',
  scope: 'openid profile email offline_access api',
  filterProtocolClaims: true,
  loadUserInfo: true
};

@Component({
  selector: 'signin',
  templateUrl: './signin.component.html'
})

export class SignInComponent implements OnInit {

  private manager = new UserManager(settings);

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.manager.signinRedirectCallback().then(function (user) {
      console.log(user);
   });

  }

}
```

Any idea why this happens? What am I missing?

Thank You

Comment: AuthService constructor is invoking an async function and it has not responded yet and you have started to test the "user"

Comment: How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Few thing to try

Change your response_type to this

```
response_type: 'id_token token'
```

and remove null in user

```
private user: User;
```

and remove these 2

```
response_mode

@Injectable({ 
  providedIn: 'root' 
})
```

Comment: "response_type: 'id_token token'" is only for hybrid flow which you should not use on SPAs.

Answer (score 0):

2 things to check:

- First, open the browser's console and see if the `signinRedirectCallback() call` is throwing any errors.
- Second, look in the application's session storage, do you see any user data populated by the authentication flow?

Another observation: you should not create instances of `UserManager` for every page; All the logic for oauth with `oidc-client` should be encapsulated in
a service that will be injected in the different pages of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `isSignedIn` method to promise-based.

```
 isSignedIn(): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.manager.getUser().then(user => {
        resolve(user != null && !user.expired);
      });
    });
  }
```

And your route guard:

```
canActivate(): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.authService.isLoggedIn().then(result => {
        if (result) {
          resolve(result);
        } else {
          this.authService.startAuthentication().finally(() => {
            reject(false);
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
```